# Searching class in a lot of subviews. Is there a better way?

Tags: ios, performance, subview, listings

I'm adding image in subviews of a scrollView, but only to a certain custom class `AsyncImageView`. This takes some time because there are a lot of subviews and the application has lost it's smooth scrolling.

```
NSArray *subviewsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[scrollView subviews]];
        for (int j = 0; j < [subviewsArray count]; j++) {
            for (AsyncImageView *checkView in [[subviewsArray objectAtIndex:j] subviews]) {
                if ([checkView isKindOfClass:[AsyncImageView class]]) {
                       [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:checkView];

                        NSString* urlTextEscaped = [[imageInfo objectAtIndex:0] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlTextEscaped];
                        if (URL)
                        {
                            checkView.imageURL = URL;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NSURL *defaultURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/user_avatar_default.jpg"];
                            checkView.imageURL = defaultURL;

                        }
                    }
                 }
               }
```

Is there a better way to access the view that I need and add image to it? Some other logic that I haven't think of.

This is the hierarchy of the scrollView

```
                                           scrollView
                                                |
                                                |
                                           MaseterView
                                                |
                                                |
                         AsyncImageView  -   TitleView - OtherImageView
```

Comment: How many AsyncImageView's do you need to support? Sounds like you should keep a local reference in either a direct pointer property, or an array if you have more than one.

Comment: There are many AsyncImageView's. I get the objects with url in a server response, and for every image that needs to be shown I call this method in whom I send an array `imageInfo` with the url as first object. `[imageInfo objectAtIndex:0]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new array with the subviews of the scroll view before you iterate it. You have 2 general options:

A. Still looping, but not done by you. Only meaningful if you have a single image view or have multiple image views that you want to update individually.

Set the tag of the image view, then use `[scrollView viewWithTag:...];`

B. If you have multiple image views and you want to update all of them at the same time.

Hold a mutable array property and add the image views to it when you create them.

Other things to think about:

1. Do you need to update all the image views - are they all on display?
2. Can you observe the scrolling of the scroll view and only start loads for images when they're on display (and cancel incomplete loads when scrolled off display)?

Comment: I kinda liked the `[scrollView viewWithTag:...];`. I'll try it and see if I can get a better performance. Thx

Comment: The array route should provide better performance because it means looping subviews ins't required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
UIView *v = [self.containerView viewWithTag:uniqueTagvalue];
```

set unique tag value for the views you need and fetch it

Comment: Ok, but how to add image to that view when I get it. Should I put all `v` views into array(`vArray`) and do `for (AsyncImageView *checkView in vArray)`?